# cakephp where conditions result array bugged

Tags: cakephp, find, conditional-statements, where-clause, cakephp-2.3

I am stuck on a weird behavior of cakePHP.
When I made a find('all'); with conditions if I take two conditions that recovers each others, my array grouped the results...

Example: First request
Conditions array:

```
array(
    (int) 1 => '1',
    'found_by_user_id' => '99',
    'Defect.status_isopen' => (int) 1
)
```

Result:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Defect' => array(
            'id' => '14701',
            'severity_id' => '3',
            'severity_title' => 'Medium',
            'found_by_user_id' => '99',
            'found_username' => 'TB',
            'assigned_to_user_id' => '7',
            'assigned_username' => 'JB',
            'version_id' => '140',
            'version_title' => '5.2',
            'project_id' => '35',
            'project_title' => 'A4L - 5',
            'found_in_build' => '',
            'fixed_in_build' => null,
            'title' => 'MyTitle',
            'content' => 'My content',
            'status_id' => '1',
            'status_title' => 'New',
            'status_isopen' => '1',
            'location_id' => '389',
            'location_title' => 'import and export',
            'nb_followers' => '0',
            'nb_media' => '1',
            'nb_linked_objects' => '1',
            'show_stopper' => '0',
            'fixed_date' => null,
            'modified' => '2013-01-18 12:09:02',
            'created' => '2013-01-18 12:09:02'
        ),
        'Media' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2195',
                'filename' => 'boxedWarning.docx',
                'dir_name' => 'legacy',
                'defect_id' => '14701',
                'content' => 'file test',
                'user_id' => '99',
                'created' => '2013-01-18 12:09:02'
            )
        ),
        'Follow' => array(),
        'PointedObject' => array()
    ),
```

etc

And when I put more conditions:
conditions array:

```
array(
    (int) 1 => '1',
    'Defect.status_id' => '1',
    'found_by_user_id' => '99',
    'Defect.status_isopen' => (int) 1
)
```

And the result bug... Cake group two parameters status_title, status_open...

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'Defect' => array(
            'id' => '14701',
            'severity_id' => '3',
            'severity_title' => 'Medium',
            'found_by_user_id' => '99',
            'found_username' => 'TBt',
            'assigned_to_user_id' => '7',
            'assigned_username' => 'JB',
            'version_id' => '140',
            'version_title' => '5.2',
            'project_id' => '35',
            'project_title' => 'A4L - 5',
            'found_in_build' => '',
            'fixed_in_build' => null,
            'title' => 'MyTitle',
            'content' => 'My content',
            'status_id' => '1',
            'location_id' => '389',
            'location_title' => 'import and export',
            'nb_followers' => '0',
            'nb_media' => '1',
            'nb_linked_objects' => '1',
            'show_stopper' => '0',
            'fixed_date' => null,
            'modified' => '2013-01-18 12:09:02',
            'created' => '2013-01-18 12:09:02'
        ),
        'stati' => array(
            'status_title' => 'New',
            'status_isopen' => '1'
        ),
        'Media' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2195',
                'filename' => 'boxedWarning.docx',
                'dir_name' => 'legacy',
                'defect_id' => '14701',
                'content' => 'file test',
                'user_id' => '99',
                'created' => '2013-01-18 12:09:02'
            )
        ),
        'Follow' => array(),
        'PointedObject' => array()
    ),
```

Look at the stati information... It has removed Status_title and status_isopen in a sub-array Stati...

Notes: I use containable behavior. And My find('all'); points to a view table. And status is one of my models.

Thanks in advance !!

EDIT: here is my paginate query:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => $this->Auth->user('page_size'), 
    'recursive'=>-1,
    'contain' => array(
        'Media',
        'Follow'=> array(
            'conditions'=>array('Follow.user_id'=>$user_id), 
            'fields' => array('id','flag')
        ),
        'PointedObject' => array(
            'order'=>array('PointedObject.linked_category_id'),
            'LinkedCategory'
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => $order
);
```

EDIT2: The MySQL Query is good...

```
SELECT
    `Defect`.`id`, `Defect`.`severity_id`, `Defect`.`severity_title`, 
    `Defect`.`found_by_user_id`, `Defect`.`found_username`, `Defect`.`assigned_to_user_id`,
    `Defect`.`assigned_username`, `Defect`.`version_id`, `Defect`.`version_title`, 
    `Defect`.`project_id`, `Defect`.`project_title`, `Defect`.`found_in_build`, 
    `Defect`.`fixed_in_build`, `Defect`.`title`, `Defect`.`content`, 
    `Defect`.`status_id`, `Defect`.`status_title`, `Defect`.`status_isopen`, 
    `Defect`.`location_id`, `Defect`.`location_title`, `Defect`.`nb_followers`, 
    `Defect`.`nb_media`, `Defect`.`nb_linked_objects`, `Defect`.`show_stopper`, 
    `Defect`.`fixed_date`, `Defect`.`modified`, `Defect`.`created`
 FROM 
    `defects_dbo`.`defects_view` AS `Defect`
 WHERE
    `Defect`.`status_id` = 1
    AND `found_by_user_id` = 99
    AND `Defect`.`status_isopen` = 1

 ORDER BY `Defect`.`id` DESC 
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: is there a reason you're doing `(int) 1 => '1'` ?

Comment: Please post the actual `find()`

Comment: yep 1=>1 is used to init my array $conditions and return all results by default

Comment: don't use `1=1` .. just set an empty array.

Comment: ok ok but it did not resolve the problem...Why in the second case, cake group my two 'conditions' results in a sub-array: 'stati' => array(
            'status_title' => 'New',
            'status_isopen' => '1'
        ),

Comment: and recursive = -1, 0, 1, or 2 - not false

Comment: Don't need to repeat the question - just trying to help out.  I assume there's some code you're leaving out that's making it do that, but - hard to tell from what's provided.  What version of cake are you using?  (usually include that as a tag)

Comment: Sorry man... I'm using cake 2.3.0 and I've try with recursive: -1 and it gave my the same result...

Comment: I workaround the problem by using afterFind, and replacing my removed field in the main array.

     public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
        
          foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
              if (!isset($val['Defect']['status_title']) && isset($val['stati']['status_title'])) {
                  $results[$key]['Defect']['status_title'] = $results[$key]['stati']['status_title'];
              }
          }
        
        return $results;
    }

But if anyone know why cakephp acts this way, I really would like the answer.

thanks Dave for your help!

Comment: try just removing any/all `'field'=>` specifications.

Comment: I have removed all 'field'=> specifications but no changes...